# MS-Access VBA magically converting unicode strings?

Tags: ms-access, vba, unicode

First, I admit not being a VB expert, but I was asked to check our database system taking care of handling the languages of our application.  The issue is that some characters with accent seem to magically be converted without them.

For example, the Polish word "przesunąć" will be stored as "przesunac" in the record field at the time of the call to Recordset.MoveNext.  "Unicode Compression" is set to true on that column, but I doubt it's related.  I'm trying to find out what makes this magic conversion because I don't want it.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;145727 says "Visual Basic assumes that the world outside of itself still uses the single-byte ANSI model. Any strings passed as parameters to an external function will be converted by Visual Basic from their internal Unicode representation to an ANSI representation before the call to the function is made."   That means that VB is the one doing the magic.  How do I turn this off then?

Answer (score 3):

Someone stated at http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/no-unicode-dao-recordset-t1102041.html that " the Recordset contains correct data but that the Debugger window and Tooltips can't display Unicode strings".  Interesting.  Dumb, but interesting.

Fine, but why are the strings in ANSI in the file?  Well, the next post in the same thread reads "If you want to write in Unicode with VBA, my feeling would be that you must
write in binary mode; not in Text mode."  This lead me to http://accessblog.net/2007/06/how-to-write-out-unicode-text-files-in.html where I got my final answer.

Case solved.